# How do I do closures in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, closures, elisp

I'm trying to create a function on the fly that would return one constant value.

In JavaScript and other modern imperative languages I would use closures:

```
function id(a) {
    return function() {return a;};
}
```

but Emacs lisp doesn't support those.

I can create mix of identity function and partial function application but it's not supported either.

So how do I do that?

Comment: As far as I have heard, JavaScript is actually rather functional.

Comment: It depends on one's point of view. For me if most of the code in the language is imperative then it's imperative. Which is the case here.

Comment: As of version 24, Emacs now has lexical scoping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stupid idea: how about:

```
(defun foo (x)
  `(lambda () ,x))

(funcall (foo 10))  ;; => 10
```

Comment: This breaks down when you want to write something like: (lexical-let
((a 0)) (cons (lambda () a) (lambda (new-a) (setf a new-a))))

Answer (score 35):

Found another solution with lexical-let

```
(defun foo (n) 
    (lexical-let ((n n)) #'(lambda() n)))

(funcall (foo 10)) ;; => 10
```

Answer (score 13):

**Real (Not Fake) Closures in Emacs 24.**

Although Emacs 24 has lexical scooping when the variable **lexical-binding** has value **t**, the **defun** special form doesn’t work properly in lexically bound contexts (at least not in Emacs 24.2.1.)  This makes it difficult, but *not* impossible, to define real (not fake) closures.  For example:

```
(let ((counter 0))
   (defun counting ()
    (setq counter (1+ counter))))
```

will not work as expected because the symbol **counter** in the **defun** will be bound to the global variable of that name, if there is one, and not the lexical variable define in the **let**. When the function **counting** is called, if the global variable doesn’t, exist then it will obviously fail. Hoever if there is such a global variable it be updated, which is probably not what was intended and could be a hard to trace bug since the function might appear to be working properly.

The byte compiler does give a warning if you use **defun** in this way and presumably the issue will be addressed in some future version of Emacs, but until then the following macro can be used:

```
(defmacro defun** (name args &rest body)
  "Define NAME as a function in a lexically bound context.

Like normal `defun', except that it works correctly in lexically
bound contexts.

\(fn NAME ARGLIST [DOCSTRING] BODY...)"
  (let ((bound-as-var (boundp  `,name)))
    (when (fboundp `,name)
      (message "Redefining function/macro: %s" `,name))
    (append
     `(progn
        (defvar ,name nil)
        (fset (quote ,name) (lambda (,@args) ,@body)))
     (if bound-as-var
         'nil
         `((makunbound `,name))))))
```

If you define **counting** as follows:

```
(let ((counter 0))
  (defun** counting ()
    (setq counter (1+ counter))))
```

it will work as expected and update the lexically bound variable **count** every time it is invoked, while returning the new value.

**CAVEAT:** The macro will not work properly if you try to **defun**** a function with the same name as one of the lexically bound variables. I.e if you do something like:

```
(let ((dont-do-this 10))
  (defun** dont-do-this ()
    .........
    .........))
```

I can’t imagine anyone actually doing that but it was worth a mention.

Note: I have named the macro **defun**** *so that it doesn’t clash with the macro **defun**** in the **cl** package, however it doesn’t depend in any way on that package.

Comment: Can you give a complete example? It seems that the code (let ((counter 0))
  (defun** counting ()
    (setq counter (1+ counter)))) don't work as expected.

Comment: The limitation wrt to defining closures with `defun` was lifted in Emacs-24.3 (where `defun` is now defined as a macro rather than a special form).  So since 24.3 `defun` works like your `defun**` macro (tho without the broken `(defvar ,name nil)` and fixing various other minor downsides such as the use of `fset` rather than `defalias` and handling of so called "dynamic docstrings" which required changes in the bytecompiler).

Answer (score 7):

Emacs lisp only has dynamic scoping. There's a `lexical-let` macro that approximates lexical scoping through a rather terrible hack.

Comment: Of course, the `rather terrible hack' is what goes on under the covers
of other language implementations.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs 24 has lexical binding.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LexicalBinding

Comment: Refer also to the section in the GNU Emacs manual on [Variable Scoping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html#Variable-Scoping)

Answer (score 4):

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-

(defun create-counter ()
  (let ((c 0))
    (lambda ()
      (setq c (+ c 1))
      c)))

(setq counter (create-counter))

(funcall counter) ; => 1
(funcall counter) ; => 2
(funcall counter) ; => 3 ...
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FakeClosures