# Getting elisp to return a function as return value

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to create a function in elisp that returns another function. I looked at this answer to a similar question ([how to return function in elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344077/how-to-return-function-in-elisp)) but did not understand the answer (I'm literally just starting learning elisp today, so please excuse my ignorance). I thought a simpler example would help. First, consider a function that test whether a number is divisible by 5:

```
(defun divisible-by-5 (x) 
  ;; tests whether a number is divsible by 5. 
  (setq remainder (% x 5))
  (if (= remainder 0) 1 0)
)
```

This works fine:

```
(divisible-by-5 25)
1
```

Now suppose I want to create a function that can create more of these kinds of test functions---something like:

```
(defun divisible-by-z (z)
  (lambda (z) 
  (setq remainder (% x z))
  (if (= remainder 0) 1 0))
 )
```

This does *not* work. E.g.,

```
(defun divisible-by-3 (divisible-by-z 3))
(divisible-by-3 4)
```

returns an error. I think even seeing an elisp-idiomatic example of how one would implement this pattern would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you have `lexical-binding` enabled. The simplest way to do so is to evaluate `(setq lexical-binding t)` in your current buffer. More information on the topic can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html).

Your definition of `divisible-by-z` is basically correct except that you have a mistype (naming both parameters `z`; the lambda's parameter should be `x`). Also, it would be more idiomatic to introduce the binding for `remainder` with `let` - `setq` is generally reserved for mutating bindings that already exist. Here's the result:

```
(defun divisible-by-z (z)
  (lambda (x)
    (let ((remainder (% x z)))
      (if (= remainder 0) 1 0))))
```

You can't use `defun` to create `divisible-by-3` in quite the way you've tried - it's expecting the argument list for a new function to be where you have the call to `divisible-by-z`.

You could either create a global, dynamic binding with

```
(defvar divisible-by-3 (divisible-by-z 3))
```

Or a local, lexical binding with

```
(let ((divisible-by-3 (divisible-by-z 3)))
  ...)
```

Either way, you'll then need to use `funcall` to call the function

```
(funcall divisible-by-3 9) ; => 1
```

Of course, you could also skip giving it its own name entirely and simply

```
(funcall (divisible-by-z 3) 10) ; => 0
```

`funcall` is necessary because Emacs Lisp is (basically) a Lisp-2, meaning it can attach both a function and a value to a given symbol. So when you're treating functions as values (returning one from a function or passing one in to a function as a parameter) you essentially have to tell it to look in that value "cell" rather than the usual function cell. If you search for "Lisp-1 vs Lisp-2" you'll find more than you want to know about this.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```
(defun divisible-by-3 (x)
  (funcall (divisible-by-z 3) x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (perhaps simpler) method is to include `x` as a variable to be passed to the function:

```
(defun divisible-by-z (x z) "
Check if x is divisible by z.
If so, return 0.
If not, return the remainder."
   (if (% x z) (% x z) 0))
```

thus:

```
(divisible-by-z 5 2) --> 1
(divisible-by-z 4 2) --> 0
```