# format of lambda in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, eval, quote, backquote

I'm tring to apply closure in emacs lisp.And I find a post here:
[How do I do closures in Emacs Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593383/how-do-i-do-closures-in-emacs-lisp)

with some code like:

> (defun foo (x)   `(lambda () ,x)) (message (string (funcall (foo
>   66))))

But following the emacs [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions) lambda should be formated like
'(lambda () x)  ==> using this format ,I got an  ERROR :Symbol's value as variable is void: x

When " ,  " is add betwenn "()" and "x" ,everything goes right .

Why?

Comment: Emacs Lisp has no closures like that. Read also the documentation of FUNCALL how to use it.

Comment: In Emacs 24 your code works, as long as `lexical-binding` is set for the buffer/file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because Emacs Lisp is dynamically scoped thus `foo` returns a lambda where `x` is free. That's what the error tells you.

To do a closure in Emacs Lisp you have to use `lexical-let` which simulates a lexical binding and therefore allows you to make a real closure.

```
(defun foo (x)
  (lexical-let ((x x))
               (lambda () x)))

(message (string (funcall (foo 66))))
```

Here are some links from the Emacs Wiki:

1. [Dynamic Binding Vs Lexical Binding](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding)
2. [Fake Closures](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FakeClosures)

Note that you could have defined `x` with a let like this:

```
(defun foo (x)
  (lambda () x))

(message (string (let ((x 66)) (funcall 
                                (foo 'i-dont-care)))))
```

Comment: Actually, taht code is even hackier, it is equivalent to: `(defun foo (x) (list 'lambda nil x))` so `(foo 66)` returns `(lambda () 66)` and I am sure there'#s all sorts of inadvertent capturing possible here...

Comment: @Vatine: Yes I know what does the backquote, but you have to understand what does the quote => it prevents the evaluation of the form, so `(defun foo (x) '(lambda () x))`, `(foo 66)` returns `(lambda () x)` and then you try to funcall this, but the interpreter doesn't know what it is. Contrary to the backquote which allows the evaluation with the comma.

Comment: But in the original post there is a backquote, so it returns `(lambda () 66)`, not `(lambda () x)`.

Comment: @Vatine: Yes, and with a backquote it works. If the documentation says that lambda should be formated with a quote it's for higher-order like this `(mapcar '(lambda (el) (+ el 1))` '(1 2 3 4))`, but in your case you want to evaluate `x` to build your closure.

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives a bit of detail behind the first part of @Daimrod's correct answer.

Your question is *why* this works:

```lisp
(defun foo (x) `(lambda () ,x)) (message (string (funcall (foo 66))))
```

and this doesn't work:

```lisp
(defun foo (x) '(lambda () x)) (message (string (funcall (foo 66))))
```

First, the quote (`'`) is unnecessary in the second, because in Emacs Lisp lambda forms are self-evaluating.  That is, `'(lambda (...) ...)` generally acts the same as `(lambda (...) ...)`.

But what does the backquote (`` ` ``), instead of quote (`'`), **do**?

Inside a backquoted expression, a comma (`,`) means replace the next expression by its value, that is, evaluate it.  So this:

```lisp
`(lambda () ,x)
```

means create and return a list whose first element is the symbol `lambda` (that's not evaluated), whose second element is `()` (that's not evaluated), and whose third element is the **value** of variable `x`.  It's equivalent to evaluating this code, which uses function `list`:

```lisp
(list 'lambda '() x)
```

That's what you want: *replace* `x` by its current value (in this case, its value inside the function `foo`, that is, the value of `foo`'s argument).

But this:

```lisp
'(lambda () x)
```

(and likewise, because a lambda form is self-evaluating, `(lambda () x)`) returns this list: `(lambda () x)`. And when that's evaluated using dynamic scoping (the default scoping regime in Emacs Lisp), `x` is unbound - it has no value.  So a void-variable error is raised.