# why this code couldn't work with Emacs-lisp

Tags: closures, elisp

I wan't to implement a closure behavior in `Elisp`, here is the code:

```
(setq lexical-binding t)
(setq var 3)
(require 'cl)
(defun foo (n)
  #'(lambda (i)
    (incf n i)))
(defvar bar (foo var))
(funcall bar 1)
```

what I want get is that every time I run the expr:`(funcall bar 1)` it will increment the result of the expr by `1`. I don't know why it can't work, can someone explain it to me?
I found a similar question in the [How do I do closures in Emacs Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/593383/930125) but I can't understand it. My Emacs version is 24.2.1 which seems support the `lexical scoping`.

Comment: Every time you evaluate `(funcall bar 1)` you will get the next number in the sequence (starting with 4).  Your code does create a closure.  Were you expecting `var` to change value? (verified with Emacs 24.1)

Comment: @Trey Jackson I got the error that `setq: Symbol's value as variable is void: n`, it can't work in my Emacs, I don't want the `var` to change, I just want to see How to make the closure work. is it works in your Emacs?

Comment: Yup, the code works as is in my Emacs (24.1), I just cut/paste/evaled it again.

Comment: very wired... It just can't work on my Emacs (24.2.1) for windows and for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The `lexical-binding` variable is fairly special, I strongly recommend to never use `setq` on it.  Only define it via a `-*- lexical-binding: t -*-` in a comment on the first line (and that comment only takes effect after you re-visit the corresponding file).

Comment: you mean `;-*- lexical-binding: t -*-` on the first line?

Comment: More or less, yes.  The first line should normally look like `;;; <FILENAME> --- <DESCRIPTION>` so just add `-*- lexical-binding: t -*-` after the description.