# How to generate adder function in lisp?

Tags: lisp, elisp

I need to make a function that generates functions like this:

```
(defun add3 (val) (+ 3 val))
```

It should be usable like this:

```
(setq adder7 nil)
(fset 'adder7 (make-adder 7))
(adder7 3)
     => 10
```

Ideally, function make-adder should return lambdas that do not have any symbols inside other then their parameter, for example:

```
(make-adder 7)
      => (lambda (val) (+ 7 val))
```

**Update**

I have tried following naive realisation:

```
(defun make-adder (n)
  (lambda (x) (+ n x)))
```

But that generates a lambdda that contains free symbol (not numeric constant!) and its usage fails.

```
(defalias 'add1 (make-adder 1))
(add1 2)
       => Debugger error void-variable n

(let ((n 5))
  (add1 2))
       => 7
```

Which is not what i want to get at all.

Comment: what's the actual problem you have with this task? What did you try?

Comment: Actual problem i have is: naive approach fails to work. That is, i get lambda containing free symbol which consequently fails to work

Comment: So this is in fact an Emacs Lisp question? I'll update the answer

Comment: Yes, I should have tagged is as such - common-lisp tag was added by someone else.

Comment: Does the answer to [Emacs lisp: why does this sexp cause an invalid-function error?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17102051/1281433) help here?  Ultimately it comes down to the same thing:  emacs's dynamic scoping.  And I think that the answer there, using emacs's `lexical-let` might be a better solution that constructing a function with an injected constant value, at least in some contexts.

Comment: I did want a constant there, though. Thanks for mentioning lexical-let, it will come in handy as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Emacs

Emacs relies on [dynamic scoping](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding) by default. That's why the `n` symbol inside the returned lambda refers to an unbound variable. Either you toggle lexical scoping or you build a lambda form with the current value of `n`, as follows:

```
(defun make-adder (n)
  `(lambda (x) (+ ,n x)))
```

And then:

```
(defalias  'add1 (make-adder 1))
(add1 3)
=> 4
```

#### Common Lisp

I originally thought the question was about Common Lisp (*fset* should have given me a hint), where you only have to do this:

```
(defun make-adder (n)
  (lambda (x) (+ n x)))
```

Your function takes a `n` and returns an anonymous function, which takes another parameter `x` and produces the result.
But wait, `make-adder` is just a special case of [partially applying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application) some arguments to a function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application) for details on the distinction between currying and partial application). The general approach to partially apply functions is:

```
(defun partial (function &rest partial-args)
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (apply function (append partial-args args))))
```

For example:

```
(let ((3+ (partial #'+ 3)))
  (funcall 3+ 7))
=> 10
```

Comment: I must ask you for a reference on the syntax you have used. This seems to be just what i needed yet i never saw it in elisp manual

Comment: @Srv19 backquotes: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593383/how-do-i-do-closures-in-emacs-lisp) and its answers are quite informative.

Comment: Is the backquote solution better than using `lexical-let` to capture the variable?  Since it's "read-only" in this case, I guess it'd be the same, but this weren't just an adder, but an accumulator or something, you'd *want* a closure over a binding, not a anonymous function with an injected constant value.  See, e.g., [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17108245/1281433) (disclaimer, it's mine) for an example.  (Actually, that's the answer in which I first learned about emacs's lexical-let.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You are right, I should have mentioned lexical-let. Somehow the answer evolved from being CL-only to Emacs+CL, and I am not really satisfied with it. I'll edit later when I have more time.

Comment: Well, in my use case function will be called exactly once but at undetermined moment in time, so there is no reason to capture a variable

Answer (score 2):

[coredump-'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386399/1281433) address the right issue:  emacs's dynamic scoping means that you no longer have access to the value of n that was in scope when your **adder** function was called.  Rather than using backquote to construct a function with the constant injected, though,  I think that it might be more descriptive to use emacs's **lexical-let**, since what you're looking for is a lexical closure. Just to be clear, here's the behavior you're getting now, with dynamic scoping:

```
(defun dyn-adder (n)
  (lambda (x)
    (+ n x)))

(funcall (dyn-adder 3) 5)
;; (void-variable n) error...
```

And here's how you can use **lexical-let** to get an actual lexical closure:

```
(defun lex-adder (n)
  (lexical-let ((n n))
    (lambda (x)
      (+ n x))))

(funcall (adder 3) 5)
;; 8
```

There isn't much difference between the backquote solution and lexical-let in defining a simple adder, but there are contexts where it's important to actually have a variable that you're referencing.  E.g., if you wanted to create an *accumulator*, you'd need that local state.  With dynamic scoping you'd get the same void-variable error:

```
(defun dyn-accumulator (n)
  (lambda (x)
    (incf n x)))

(let ((acc (dyn-accumulator 5)))
  (funcall acc 3)
  (funcall acc 8))
;; (void-variable n) error...
```

With a backquote approach, you'll get a different error.  (I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly, though.  I think that the error I'm getting is from trying to funcall a list, not from the function having a constant in it.  But in any case, it should be clear that **(lambda (x) (incf 5 x))** won't work, because you can't increment the constant value.)

```
(defun bq-accumulator (n)
  `(lambda (x)
     (incf ,n x)))

(let ((acc (bq-accumulator 5)))
  (funcall acc 3)
  (funcall acc 8))
;; wrong type argument error...
```

But with **lexical-let**, we have a real variable that we can modify:

```
(defun lex-accumulator (n)
  (lexical-let ((n n))
    (lambda (x)
      (incf n x))))

(let ((acc (lex-accumulator 5)))
  (funcall acc 3)
  (funcall acc 8))
;; 16
```

I learned about and described **lexical-let** more in an answer I wrote for [Emacs lisp: why does this sexp cause an invalid-function error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17102051/1281433);  that may be useful information here, as well.