# Elisp: Bind a lambda in a Let and execute it

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am attempting to understand the `lambda` notion found within Emacs Lisp.

In `ielm`, executing:

```
((lambda (x) (* x x)) 5)
```

gives us `25`, and

```
(let ((x 4)) (* x x))
```

gives us `16`.  However when I do:

```
(let ((f (lambda (x) (* x x)))) (f 7))
```

it does not give me `49`, but instead informs me:

```
*** Eval error ***  Symbol's function definition is void: f
```

Don't know why, I am sure the syntax is right and f is defined in the `let`?

**Using `cl-flet` to define `let`-ed function**

We *can* actually do this without using `funcall`.  The `cl` module includes standard functions from Common Lisp.  We first import it:

```
(require 'cl)
```

Thereafter we can use `cl-flet` to define our function:

```
(cl-flet ((f (x) (* x x)))
  (f 7))
```

Comment: Does `(let ((f (lambda (x) (* x x)))) (funcall f 7))` work?

Comment: I think you may find http://stackoverflow.com/a/17108245/1281433 helpful, though the question is a bit more complex.

Comment: @sds That definitely describes some of the issue, but it doesn't mention **funcall** or **apply**, so it doesn't really answer the question, in my opinion.

Comment: @sds Don't think it is a duplicate, not reached the level where I even know what `Lisp-1` and `Lisp-2` are.

Comment: @TahirHassan: that question tells you what you need to learn to be able to answer your question yourself.

Comment: @sds you are right, but it will be a long road ahead for me to even see *why* you are right.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: that question is much more high level. It teaches the user how to fish instead of giving them the fish, so to speak.

Comment: @TahirHassan: this is the road you need to take ASAP. Good luck! :-)

Comment: @sds But looking at the documentation for funcall and apply would also lead to the understanding that's needed, as well as the subtle differences that might exist between different Lisps in the different categories.  E.g., I don't know offhand whether Elisp uses spreadable arglists like CL's apply does.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd be surprised if this isn't a duplicate, but I can't find it readily here on Stack Overflow. In "Lisp-2" languages (e.g., Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp), there are separate namespaces for functions and variables.  A function call looks like either:

```
((lambda ...) ...) ; call the lambda function
```

or

```
(f ...) ; call the function binding of f
```

If you want to call the function that is the value of a variable, then you need to use funcall or apply:

```
(apply f ...)

(funcall f ...)
```

The difference between **apply** and **funcall** is well documented in other places, but the quick difference is that **apply** expects an argument list (in some Lisps, a "spreadable argument list"), whereas **funcall** takes the arguments directly.  E.g.,

```
(let ((f (lambda (a b) (+ a b))))
  (funcall f 1 2)      ; arguments directly
  (apply f '(1 2)))    ; arguments in a list
```

In a "Lisp-1", (like Scheme), you don't need funcall, since there's only one space for bindings.  In Scheme you *can* do:

```
(let ((f (lambda (a b) (+ a b))))
  (f 1 2))
```

The difference between Lisp-1 and Lisp-2 languages is described more in [What is the difference between Lisp-1 and Lisp-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2).  The big difference is when the system sees a function call, how it figures out what function to call.  In a Lisp-1, variables have values, and that's all.  So when the system sees something like:

```
(f ...)
```

f is a variable, and the only possible thing to call is the value of f.  In a Lisp-2, the systems tries to call the *function value* of f, which doesn't have to have anything do with the value of the *variable* f.  That can be a bit confusing at first, but it's actually pretty handy in many cases, because it makes it harder to accidentally obscure functions with common names.  E.g., in a Lisp-1, you'll see lots of people use `lst` as an argument name instead of `list`, because if they named the argument `list`, then they couldn't use the (standard) function `list` within the function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I see that the difference between `funcall` and `apply` is that of JS's `call` and `apply` (except there is no such thing as a `this` reference).

Comment: @TahirHassan I'd phrase it the other way around (i.e., that JS's call and apply are like Lisp's funcall and apply) because Lisp is older, but yes, it's the same principle.